# Emu8086 emulator link for macOS

Tags: macos, assembly, simulator, emu8086

Does anybody know, how can I install emu8086 emulator, it's necessary for my processor lecture?

I google it, but i can't find anything on the search. All links for windows, I have a MacBook so somebody have a link for MacOS emu8086?

Comment: Try running the windows version through [Whisky](https://getwhisky.app), which is a MacOS optimized wine wrapper. I use it and it works great!